# PhoneGap Geolocation Timeout Error

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, geolocation

I am receiving a Geolocation Timeout Error quite often on my phonegap application. This was happening with 1.1.0, but is also happening with the new 1.2.0.

Any workarounds or suggestions? I notice a lot of people are having it. Sometimes I get it, sometimes I don't. But it happens enough to cause an issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I got the same in ipod touch,but worked in iPhone and android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
                var myOptions = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,
                                                         myOptions);
```

Comment: That fixed it, but I went to Titanium Mobile. Much better than Phone Gap in my opinion.